# Graph api - Like / until - since

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

Is there a possibility to use the parameters "since" and "until" in the likes request?

What I'm trying:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?limit=500&offset=0&since=2011-01-01&access_token=...
```

I liked a post today, but it is not working. It can only show 2 pages which I liked in the past.

When using FQL, it is working as expected, but the "since" nor "until" parameter are working..

Also tried with FQL, but can't get it working:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=' . rawurlencode('SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id = me() LIMIT 500') . '&access_token=...
```

I think it is not possible to use those parameters on a like, am I correct?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm wondering the same thing.

Comment: Found this: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/138185876318491?browse=search_50e5a4bbadc8e5471828081

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for pagination, which is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/).

At the time of this answer it says...

"The following Graph API connections are cursor-based with more coming soon:

```
/photos
/albums
/links
/notes
/admins
/comments
```

"

and it looks like there is already a bug filed requesting that '/likes' be added to the list as noted (it can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/138185876318491?browse=search_50e5a4bbadc8e5471828081))

HOWEVER...

The likes come back in chronological order so you don't have to gather all of them to find the ones since a particular date.  I've got no idea if you can count on this or not so use this at your own risk.

(A side note: I dream of the day when Facebook actually grows up enough to deliver a mature API.)

Comment: this is an old question, but just in case.. i'd like to say you can remember the last person to like something, but if that person unlikes it, then everything will fall apart! or if he unlikes, then likes later!  the best option is to increase the limit (do some testing!).